# Can't create table <tablename> errno 150

Tags: mysql, sql, database, errno

Here is my SQL script

```
CREATE TABLE tracks(
track_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
account_id int,
track_name varchar(255),
track_path varchar(255),
track_art_path varchar(255),
track_desc text,
primary key(track_id),
FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts_profile(accnt_id)
)
```

I don't see any syntax errors. Everything looks fine. My Database Engine is innoDB. but how come I keep on receiving this error?

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'beatbeast.tracks' (errno: 150)
```

It's not showing what line where the error is.

Comment: 0th question: is table `accounts_profile` exists? Are the exact types of `tracks.account_id` the same as `accounts_profile.accnt_id` ?

Comment: Please also post the structure of `accounts_profile`. If the data types of `account_id` and `accounts_profile.accnt_id` are not the same (such as one is unsigned), the FK will fail with errno 150.

Comment: accounts_profile does exist in my Database.

Comment: @Michael account_id is unsigned.

Comment: @user962206 Not according to your create statement above. It is a signed int here, and if it's unsigned in `accounts_profile`, it must be unsigned here too

Comment: okay alright.  I was going to select you as best answer but you just commented is there by any chance you can post your answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150

Comment: @user962206 added as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errno 150 is generally the result of a mismatch between the exact data types of the main table's referenced column, and the referencing column.  In your case, `tracks.account_id` is a signed `INT`, but the column it references `accounts_profile.accnt_id` is `INT UNSIGNED`.  So you must create the `tracks` table using `INT UNSIGNED` for `account_id` as well:

```
CREATE TABLE tracks(
  track_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  account_id int UNSIGNED,
  track_name varchar(255),
  track_path varchar(255),
  track_art_path varchar(255),
  track_desc text,
  primary key(track_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts_profile(accnt_id)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> If MySQL reports an error number 1005 from a CREATE TABLE statement,
>   and the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed
>   because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.

Check that the datatype of `accounts_profile.accnt_id` matches `tracks.account_id` exactly.  Currently one is an `int`, so the other must also be an `int`.

Furhter, the documentation suggests to call:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

after you get the error message for a more detailed explanation.