# MySQL: errno(150), cannot create table (related to foreign keys)

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I want to use cascading in my project to simplify certain processes. I created these two queries as well as a couple more but all child tables throw the same error on execution. They worked when I used `MyISAM` as the engine, but on further testing and research I figured that it does not support cascading, so I switched the engine to `InnoDB` which triggered these errors. I've looked at a couple of forums and threads with the same problem but I just can't seem to figure out where the actual problem lies. Can someone help?

ParentTable:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `branches` ( `branch_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `key` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `short_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `city` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `timezone` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, UNIQUE(`key`), PRIMARY KEY (`branch_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Child Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` ( `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `branch_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `path` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `use_google_analytics` BOOLEAN NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`branch_id`) REFERENCES `branches`(`branch_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Error:

```
1005: Can't create table 'files' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: It's not a collation issue, it's a foreign key definition issue.

Have a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150

Comment: Alright thanks, I fixed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your foreign key

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But your `branch_id` is defined as `NOT NULL`. That won't work.

You want your `branch_id` never be `null` but then the foreign key related data gets removed you want it set to `NULL` with the `CASCADE` option.

So either change removd the `ON DELETE CASCADE` or allow `NULL` in the foreign key. This works

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b199)

Comment: Can you show me what I have to alter in my case? I cannot remove the ON DELETE CASCADE since that is the exact behavior I need. Simply changing NOT NULL to NULL or remove it completely did not work.

Comment: Thank you, I just tested everything again and this time it seems to execute correctly even with both keys set to NOT NULL