# Problems in creation database table

Tags: mysql

I created a database that contains 4 tables.
but when I entry the fourth table an error appears,this table have a primary key and 3 foreign key to the other tables.
Here is the table using mySQL :

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
id_product  SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
image SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
stock SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
category  SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY(id_product),
CONSTRAINT fk_image_id_image
FOREIGN KEY (image)
REFERENCES Image(id_image),
CONSTRAINT fk_stock_id_stock
FOREIGN KEY (stock)
REFERENCES Stock(id_stock),
CONSTRAINT fk_category_id_category
FOREIGN KEY (category)
REFERENCES Category(id_category)
)
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

when i execute it ,an error appears as follows :

> #1005 - Can't create table 'gestion_de_stock.product' (errno: 150)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Can't create table (errno: 150)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Comment: can you test out creation of the table (execute, check out error, drop repeat as necessary) and each time eliminate a different fk/constraint until you find out which one is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the columns being used in your foreign keys have the same data type in both tables.

Comment: And same definition / sizes / signed or unsigned / etc.

Comment: Pretty much the same everything except name.