# Cannot make 2 foreign keys, "errno: 150"

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm working on an assignment and came across an error making foreign keys on one of them.

First table:

```
CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURERS
(
Manufacturers_ID int(5) UNIQUE,
Name varchar(15) UNIQUE,
City varchar(30),
State char(2),
Zip char(5),
Phone char(10),
PRIMARY KEY (Manufacturers_ID)
)
ENGINE= innodb;
```

Second Table

```
CREATE TABLE OWNERS
(
Owner_ID int(10),
First_Name varchar(15),
Last_Name varchar(15),
City varchar(30),
State char(2),
Gender varchar(1),
Date_of_Birth varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (Owner_ID)
)
ENGINE= innodb;
```

Third table

```
CREATE TABLE CARS
(
Vehicle_Identification_Number int(17) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Manufacturers_ID int(5) UNIQUE,
Owner_ID int(10) UNIQUE,
Model varchar(25),
Manufaturer_Year int(4),
Mileage int(10),
Price int(10),
PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_Identification_Number),
FOREIGN KEY (Manufacturers_ID) REFERENCES MANUFACTURERS (Manufactures_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Owner_ID) REFERENCES OWNERS (Owner_ID)
)
ENGINE= innodb;
```

When I try to execute the third table, I get the message:

"An error has occurred while executing your SQL command.

ERROR: Can't create table 'ds0004.CARS' (errno: 150)"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the foreign reference in `CARS`.  This is the correct version:

```
CREATE TABLE CARS
(
Vehicle_Identification_Number int(17) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Manufacturers_ID int(5) ,
Owner_ID int(10) ,
Model varchar(25),
Manufaturer_Year int(4),
Mileage int(10),
Price int(10),
PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_Identification_Number),
FOREIGN KEY (Manufacturers_ID) REFERENCES MANUFACTURERS (Manufacturers_ID),
--------------------------------------------------------------------^
FOREIGN KEY (Owner_ID) REFERENCES OWNERS (Owner_ID)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I probably would have never found that mistake.