# More Details for MySQL's errorno:150

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP's PDO driver/API/library to create some tables in MySQL. When MySQL can't create a table due to a foreign key constraint problem, it returns the following error

> Can't create table 'dbname.table_name' (errno: 150)

Is there anyway to have MySQL tell you (or to automatically lookup/analyze) **why** it couldn't create the table.  For example, if you attempt to create a table with 10 foreign keys, and one key is invalid, is there a way to have MySQL tell you which one is the problematic key?  Or do you need to rely on human intelligence and debugging to figure this out for yourself?

Comment: `show engine status innodb` will have a "last foreign key error" section that tells you why an FK operation failed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150

Check this post

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've been able to come on this is using the `perror` command

It won't give fine grained details, but it will give you a plain english explanation of the error code.

```
$ perror 150
MySQL error code 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

$ perror 151
MySQL error code 151: Cannot add a child row
```