# Error creating table: Key column doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried create these tables:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Articls (
            id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
            name VARCHAR(254) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL      
) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci";



$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tags (
            id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
            id_articls INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   
            name VARCHAR(256) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,           
            FOREIGN KEY (`Tags.id_articls`) REFERENCES Articls(`Articls.id`)
) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci"
```

;

First table create  successfully but secnond I get this error:

> Error creating table: Key column 'Tags.id_articls' doesn't exist in
>   table

If I remove `Tags.` in `Tags.id_articls` and  `Tags.id_articls` I get errno: 150

Also If I try

```
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tags (
                id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
                id_articls INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   
                name VARCHAR(256) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,           
                FOREIGN KEY (Tags.id_articls) REFERENCES Articls(Articls.id)
    ) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci"
```

I get this error:

> Error creating table: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id_articls)
>   REFERENCES Articls(Articls.id)    ) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci' at
>   line 5

Comment: I think you just have to write: `FOREIGN KEY (id_articls) REFERENCES Articls(id)`

Comment: @Rizier123  I wrote in question...I get (errno: 150)

Comment: @Rizier123 is right, use id_articles instead of Tags.id_articles, since the Tags table doesn't exist yet

Comment: @MrBr1ghtSide If I use id_articles instead of Tags.id_articles, I get (errno: 150)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4061293/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key in your `Tags` table should be `id_articls` and not `Tags.id_articls`

Comment: Yes I wrote in question...I get (errno: 150)

Comment: It still says `Tags.id_articls`. You need to put the single-quotes back and make it just `id_articls` in single-quotes.