# SQL error when adding reference

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
user_id BIGINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, 
price DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
[...]
is_fulfilled TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
INDEX user_id_idx (user_id), 
PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE = INNODB;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
username VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
[...]
INDEX name_idx_idx (username), 
PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE = INNODB;
```

When I'm trying to set relationship

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT orders_user_id_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id);
```

I get this error

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'druk.#sql-b38_173' (errno: 150)
```

Is there something wrong in that tables or what?

Comment: This question has been answered previously here;
[link for answer to errno 150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150)
and here;
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a really weird error that does not seem related to your tables in their current form.  Hence, you need to recreate the tables correctly.

However, you do have a problem.  The column `orders.user_id` has a type that does not match the type of `user.id`.  You should change it to:

```
user_id INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed595) is a SQL Fidde.

I should add that defaulting the value to "1" seems strange.

Comment: The error is related to the tables, error 1005 says;
If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the correct column names and **types**, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns Error 1005 and refers to Error 150 in the error message, which means that a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. 

The foreign key types must be the same for a table replacing it.

Comment: @Intern87 . . . I wasn't clear in the answer.  I wanted to point out that the code has another error.

Comment: Thx, the problem was in different types.

Comment: fair enough, and you are right to point out default 1 is very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that both fields match the type. Either change `orders.user_id` to INT or `user.id` to `BIGINT`. It seem more reasonable to replace `orders.user_id` to `INT` unless you expect millions of users ...