# Issue of creating table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute this query:

```
create table order_details(
    Order_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Book_Id int, 
    Cust_Name varchar(50),
    Phone_No int,
    Address varchar(100),
    Order_Date DATE,
    Quantity int,
    FOREIGN KEY(Book_Id) REFERENCES book(Book_Id));
```

But the result is a MySQL Error 1005:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'bookstore.order_details' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: Do you have a `Book` table in your database?

Comment: Do you have a `book` table, does it have a column named `Book_Id`, and is its column type `int`?

Comment: [Check Here. I think the issue is same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Comment: @RitwikSen yes i do have table named Book in same database and also the field into named Book_Id with type int

Comment: @JeetPatel : Can you share the create table script for `Book` table.

Comment: Share us the table book since the error showing some error about that table.

Comment: And is it Book_id in Book a UNIQUE KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
create table order_details(
   Order_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Book_Id int, 
   Cust_Name varchar(50),
   Phone_No int,
   Address varchar(100),
   Order_Date DATE,
   Quantity int,
FOREIGN KEY(Book_Id) REFERENCES book(Book_Id));
```

Error (**150**) is being thrown because mysql is unable to reference the specified foreign key. This can be caused for a number of reasons however, I recommend taking the following steps to troubleshoot this.

A common issue that causes this error to become evasive is when you have not performed `USE my_database_name;` before executing the query. It fails because the context is either wrong or absent.

**1.)** Revise your query by adding in the name of the database in the reference

- **Example**: `` FOREIGN KEY(`Book_Id`) REFERENCES `my_database_name`.`book`(`Book_Id`)); ``

**2.)** Take a look at the `book` table and make sure `` `Book_Id` `` is the correct type `(int)` and is named exactly as you reference it. Perform the following queries and you may find your answer:

- `` SELECT `b`.`Book_Id` FROM `book` AS `b`; ``
- `` EXPLAIN `book`; ``

Selecting `Book_Id` from the referenced table will rule out typos in field naming. Explain will reveal the value type & key information that should help ensure consistency between foreign relations when investigating issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be having a 'book' table in your database or if you have one then there might not be a column named 'Book_id'