# MySQL Foreign Key Error: Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create two tables in MySQL database called `class_members` and `history`. The `class_members` table contains information about the members and is created as:

```
CREATE TABLE `class_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `mod_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The `class_members` tables is successfully created.

I am facing the problem when creating `history` table which contains `foreign key` reference to `class_members`.

The command which I used is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `History` ( 
   `history_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
   `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   `ip` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
   PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`), 
   CONSTRAINT `fk_history_member` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) 
   REFERENCES `class_members` (`username`) 
   ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

When I execute the above command I get this error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'testDB.History' (errno: 150)
```

I tried to find why I cannot read the `History` table
([about ERROR 1005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150))
 but I cannot understand why

---

Following Up on Comments, I created a new database and tried creating using the above command and I still get the error. See Attached Pic
[image]

---

Updated (Solved)

I found why the error in the above screenshot occurs. To solve that we have to add `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` to the end of the History table creation command.

```
 CREATE TABLE `History` ( 
   `history_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
   `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   `ip` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
   PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`), 
   CONSTRAINT `fk_history_member` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) 
   REFERENCES `class_members` (`username`) 
   ON UPDATE CASCADE)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: Didnt i just referenced that? Would appreciate if you could help rather than trying to get points

Comment: I'm not sure how I get points for flagging as a duplicate? If that posts helps you out, it does help or am I thinking wrong? But it appears that the targeted post is more or less a duplicate from the post you referenced.

Comment: I have googled and read all those and i am still unable to solve the problem that is why I thought to ask the question. Perhaps my syntax is wrong or i missed some concepts on foreign key. That is why i tried to put up the command

Comment: Both of your `CREATE TABLE` statements [work for me](http://rextester.com/KAASZ61400).  I also see nothing wrong with the foreign key `username` definition.  Please post a reproducible error.

Comment: @Tim i posted the exact error i got. Moreover when i run that link your provided I get this error: “Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails”

Comment: @kcc__ Really strange...I just re-ran it and got the error.  Let me try to fix it.

Comment: @Andomar It doesn't work, I just tested it again.  I have no explanation _why_ it does not work though :-(

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen works for me mysql workbench 6.3.9, mysql 5.7 and command line

Comment: @P.Salmon Yeah, it looks correct...maybe this is just Rextester acting up again.  The error message is inconsistent with what is being done (namely creating tables, no DML stuff).

Comment: @kcc_ can you tell us what tool you are using (mysqlworkbench, phpmyadmin,command line sql etc)?

Comment: @P.Salmon  I use  mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works on [rextester](http://rextester.com/AQTHU43966).

Make sure you don't already have an existing table called `history`. If I re-create the `history` table, I get:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

You can reproduce this by running the `rextester` query once, then remove the `drop table if exists history;` line, and run it again.

If you try to create the table twice in the same batch, you get this instead:

> Table 'history' already exists

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Of course, you have to drop `history` before dropping `class_members` :)

Comment: Nice catch +1 ... wouldn't have thought of this

Comment: There was still error but I managed to solve it by added `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` to the end of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is from the origin of the index. Try the code this way;

```
CREATE TABLE `class_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `mod_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
    INDEX `index_username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `History` ( 
  `history_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `ip` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`), 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_history_member` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) 
  REFERENCES `class_members` (`username`) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

**For SQLFiddle Sample;** [Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ad1b8/1/0)