# Not able to create table

Tags: mysql

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table '.\luv2code\course.frm' (errno: 150)

[image]

Can anyone tell what is the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Can't create table (errno: 150)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Comment: Can you add the table definition for instructor and the the create statement for course as text to the question please.