# errno: 150 Cant create table in database

Tags: mysql, sql

When im trying to start script it fails on this table creation process(

```
INFO: AdKats role groups table not found. Attempting to add.
[14:14:59 11] [AdKats] CREATE TABLE `adkats_rolegroups` (
                      `role_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                      `group_key` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`,`group_key`),
                      KEY `adkats_rolegroups_fk_role` (`role_id`),
                      KEY `adkats_rolegroups_fk_command` (`group_key`),
                      CONSTRAINT `adkats_rolegroups_fk_role` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `adkats_roles` (`role_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='AdKats - Connection of groups to roles'
[14:14:59 11] [AdKats] ERROR-7600: [Non-Query failed. [Adding AdKats role groups table]: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Can't create table 'TonyS-BF3.adkats_rolegroups' (errno: 150)
   в PRoConEvents.AdKats.SafeExecuteNonQuery(MySqlCommand command)
   в PRoConEvents.AdKats.SendNonQuery(String desc, String nonQuery, Boolean verbose)]
[14:15:00 33] [AdKats] ALTER TABLE adkats_settings MODIFY setting_value varchar(10000)
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061333/6060606 as it's probably the foreign key constraint causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create CONSTRAINT that references table adkats_roles column role_id.

When you create that table like for example:

```
create table adkats_roles (role_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                           INDEX name_index (role_id));
```

Then this is ok:

```
CREATE TABLE adkats_rolegroups(
role_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
group_key VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (role_id,group_key),
KEY adkats_rolegroups_fk_role (role_id),
KEY adkats_rolegroups_fk_command (group_key),
CONSTRAINT adkats_rolegroups_fk_role FOREIGN KEY (role_id) 
REFERENCES adkats_roles (role_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
COMMENT='AdKats - Connection of groups to roles'
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e14ddd5ed0feafedaff62520977573e)

According to the code OP posted in one of his comments OP has a code where he creates this table. Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9427961885da7344463e065712d7e03)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL error 150 is not very descriptive.  What it means is that the foreign key is not properly formed.  Malformed foreign keys can have multiple causes:

- The referenced table does not exist.
- The types on the referenced and referred to columns are not the same.
- The referenced column is not a key (preferably PRIMARY KEY) on the referring table.

My guess is that you simply have not created the table `adkats_roles`.  You should declare `role_id` as the primary key in this table:

```
create table adketa_roles (
    role_id int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Then you should have no problem with the code.

I should note that MySQL -- unlike other databases -- allows foreign key references to columns where *any* index is created.  This violates the spirit of foreign key references, which should be to a single row in the referenced table.  I strongly encourage you to only have foreign key references to primary keys, and not to just any indexed column(s).

Comment: I have this code;

(DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `adkats_roles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adkats_roles` (
  `role_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_key` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `role_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `role_key_UNIQUE` (`role_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='AdKats - Role List';)

Comment: Hi @Tony, just to check, this code does go before the code : `CREATE TABLE adkats_rolegroups` ? Also, a feedback to my answer would be nice from you ?

Comment: @Tony . . . That table definition looks correct (although it should be in the question not in a comment).  It needs to go before any definition where a foreign key to the table is defined.