# How to force Foreign Key (ID1, ID2) in old MySQL such as 5.0 or 5.1?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `MainTb1 (ID1 int, text varchar(255)) & MainTb2 (ID2 int, text varchar(255))`.

I am planning to create Tb1 that will contain these data

```
ID1 - ID2 - other columns....
12 - 25 - xxxx
24 - 63 - xxx
.....
```

And create Tb2 that will contain the combined (ID1, ID2) that existed in Tb1.

```
ID1 - ID2 - other columns....
12 - 25 - xxxx
.....
```

So, I tried:

```
create table Tb1 (ID1 int, ID2 int, Foreign key (ID1) references MainTb1(ID1),
 Foreign key (ID2) references MainTb2(ID2) )

create table Tb2 (ID1 int, ID2 int, Foreign key (ID1, ID2) references Tb1(ID1, ID2))
```

All I want is that the combined keys (ID1, ID2) in Tb2 only exists if there is an exact combined key (ID1, ID2) in Tb1. Ex, in Tb1 we got `(ID1=12 & ID2=25) & (24,63)`, so if user inserts `(ID1=12 & ID2=25)` into Tb2, then it will be allowed, if user inserts (12,63) int Tb2 then it will not allow.

When creating Tb2 (`create table Tb2 (ID1 int, ID2 int, Foreign key (ID1, ID2) references Tb1(ID1, ID2))`), I got 150 error in MySQL5.0, but seem if i use Mysql5.5 then there is no problem. But I can't change new Mysql version cos it's legacy system.

So How to force Foreign Key (ID1, ID2) in old  MySQL such as 5.0 or 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the keys from the table creation. Just put an `alter table` statement after your `create table` statement. In that alter table you can `add contraint foreign key ...`.

Comment: i have the same err, err 150

Comment: Have you checked the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150