# Export localhost Sql and import it on Server gives me errno 150

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I suggest something is wrong with the foreign keys, but i can't find a hint.

error while importing the sql:

```
  ALTER TABLE `claim`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_66A8F1231B7B246A` FOREIGN KEY (`purchaseOrder_id`) REFERENCES `PurchaseOrder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_66A8F1237294869C` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `Article` (`id`);

#1005 - Can't create table 'databasename.#sql-5c7_568c0' (errno: 150)
```

I also checked the conditions of this answer [MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)

But i couldn't find the mistake.

Any guesses?

Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `Article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `currency` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `tolerance` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE `claim` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `purchaseOrder_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_66A8F1231B7B246A` (`purchaseOrder_id`),
  KEY `IDX_66A8F1237294869C` (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `purchaseorder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_AA004F112ADD6D8C` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `IDX_AA004F1112136921` (`delivery_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is `purchaseorder`
--------------------------^-----------^

```
ALTER TABLE `claim`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_66A8F1231B7B246A` FOREIGN KEY (`purchaseOrder_id`) REFERENCES `purchaseorder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_66A8F1237294869C` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `Article` (`id`);
```