# I cant reference to other table mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super(
    id      int (20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cod     varchar(5)
    );


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super2(
    id2      int (20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cod2     varchar(5),
    FOREIGN KEY (cod2) REFERENCES super(cod)
    );
```

I cant create share tables please help and thanks
with FOREIGN KEY errno 150...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to search the archives before posting. This is a duplicate of [MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `cod` is not the primary key in the super table.