# MySQL foreign key ON DELETE SET NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I want to create a foreign key for a table using `ON DELETE SET NULL`, but the `ALTER` command is rejected.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Locations`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(0) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Pictures`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `Locations` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `Pictures` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

I found out so far, that there's already a BugReport in MySQL, but got closed as "expected behaviour":
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80052
*referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35042002/2889265*

My question is now, how can I implement a field in *Locations* which might by filled with a reference to a row in *Pictures* using the primary key. But it's not required to be filled. The field might stay empty or is updated to be empty later on. *(The location does no need to be pictured)*

If that row in *Pictures* is deleted, the column in *Locations* should be resetted to NULL automatically (like i would expect the ON DELETE SET NULL function)? Do i have to build a trigger or something like that to achieve my expected behaviour.

---

Environments:
  Dev:  `MariaDB 10.3.15`
  Prod: `MySQL 8.0.2`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I tried SET DEFAULT instead of SET NULL, but gets rejected too.

Comment: ah okay. Dont mind that. Its just a example/excerpt of the table to explain the situation. (0) has no effect on the values inside of that field (as far as i know). could have used int(11). I'll update the code to avoid misleading.

Comment: That would be the result, yes. There would be a reference ID to a not existing entry. So you make a lookup, only to find out, the ID is dead. This request could be spared, if the dead ID it would be removed from the cell. And thats the target, I want to achieve with on ON DELETE SET NULL.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4c54b/1 You'll see 5 locations (different storages) and 3 images. 4 of the 5 locations have assigned a picture, but #2 is not yet pictured. So in a webpage there would be an empty space for the picture of this location. If someone decides to delete picture #1 there would not be a picture for location #0 and #1. The goal of my question is, how to remove the reference from the locations-table automatically on row deletion, to set the cell with the matching references to NULL.

Comment: also a blank image.

Comment: Now i dont get your point. I want NULL instead of a broken reference in the database. Thats completly different. At the moment, i have to make sure in the sourcecode that the locations table gets updated after a deletion in the picture table. And i want it to be automated through a foreign key! Is that such a unnormal approach?

Comment: This code: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5585131fc2c050d43ad3c853bc807557 works.

Comment: Both columns must have the same data type. So add UNSIGNED  to the column id of Pictures.

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you @forpas ! Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Fine if it is solved.