# Laravel foreign key creation fails

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4. I want to create relationship with two table. one is `users` table and another is `sir` table. `users` table is already created. 
here is my `sir` table migration code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sir', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('sir');
}
```

now when I try to migrate it shows me this error

```
`  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 
`finalproject`.`#sq
l-9cc_98` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL:
alter table `sir` add constraint `sir_user_id_foreign`
foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))`
```

I have followed some tutorial but those are not working and also tried with laravel documentation, but still it is not working. anyone please help me to find a solution for this. thanks in advance.

Comment: this error throws from "available_sir" migration, not "sir" table migration

Comment: updated the question

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863886/3018183