# Can't create foreign key in PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I just cant create the foreign key, I execute the SQL, it shows successfully in console, but, nothing happens

EDIT

SQL code

```
ALTER TABLE cotacaoitens
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cotacaoitens_cotacao
FOREIGN KEY (codigoconcentrador, codigoempresa, codigocotacao) REFERENCES cotacao (codigoconcentrador, codigoempresa, codigocotacao) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Successfull message

```
ALTER TABLE cotacaoitens
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cotacaoitens_cotacao
FOREIGN KEY (codigoconcentrador, codigoempresa, codigocotacao) REFERENCES cotacao (codigoconcentrador, codigoempresa, codigocotacao) ON DELETE CASCADE
[2018-01-03 15:27:04] completed in 110ms
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: Sorry, i'm editing right now, i just don't know how to show the tables

Comment: I contributed to a good checklist for foreign key errors in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150 Please read through the checklist and see if any of them apply to your case.

Comment: I think thats the solution Bill, I changed the engine to MyISAM because I could not create the foreign key, one table was MyISAM and another was InnoDB, I'm going to change it, and if it works I comment

Comment: Right, MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys, but it won't give an error either. It just ignores the request to create the foreign key. It says, "La la la I'm not listening" and puts its fingers in its ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys, but it won't give an error
>   either. It just ignores the request to create the foreign key. It
>   says, "La la la I'm not listening" and puts its fingers in its ears.
>
> I contributed to a good checklist for foreign key errors in this
>   question:
>   [MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)
>   Please read through the checklist and see if any of them apply to your
>   case.

Bill Karwin