# Can't add my second Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE Transcripts (sID VARCHAR(7), cNo VARCHAR(10),
semester VARCHAR(20), grade CHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY (sID)
);
CREATE TABLE Students (sID CHAR(7), sName VARCHAR(20),
bDate DATE, phone VARCHAR(12), major VARCHAR(30), avgGPA VARCHAR(4), PRIMARY KEY (sID),
FOREIGN KEY (sID)
    REFERENCES Transcripts(sID)
);
CREATE TABLE Courses (cNo VARCHAR(10), cTitle VARCHAR(30),
creditHours VARCHAR(2), deptName VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (cNo),
FOREIGN KEY (cNo)
    REFERENCES Transcripts(cNo)
);
```

So whenever I run this, the first foreign key works just fine, whenever I run the next table it gives me back this error "ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint" What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to define `cNo` as a foreign key on `Courses` table, it must be primary key 
or a unique key of other table.

```
CREATE TABLE Transcripts(
  sID VARCHAR(7), 
  cNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  semester VARCHAR(20), 
  grade CHAR(1), 
  PRIMARY KEY (sID)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fddf8

changing Transcripts, as I've written above wil solve your problem.

Comment: But, if you can make `cNo` `UNIQUE`, then it may as well be the `PRIMARY KEY`, thereby making `sID` useless?  Once you have done that, you may as well merge the table with the other table having `cNo` as the PK??

Comment: Allen -- did you verify that this fix works for your data before 'approving' the Answer?

Comment: Rick, making `cNo` unique just makes `cNo` to be a candidate for a foreign key to be used on other table. I do not advice to use that way, and completely agree with your rationale, but Allen asked how to make it possible to add `cNo` as a FK and I've verily answered this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the foreign key that produces the error:

```
FOREIGN KEY (cNo)
    REFERENCES Transcripts(cNo)
```

But the `Transcripts(cNo)` is not part of any KEY in that table.

A foreign key must reference column(s) of a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY of the parent table.

See [MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150) for a good checklist required for a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Index the foreign key column before adding the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE Courses (cNo VARCHAR(10), cTitle VARCHAR(30),
    creditHours VARCHAR(2), deptName VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (cNo),
    INDEX (cNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (cNo)
        REFERENCES Transcripts(cNo)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the logic backwards?  Shouldn't `Transcripts have two FKs referencing the other two tables?  And, as already pointed out, declare the other two tables first.