# MySQL Adding Foreign Key Error 1215

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I know such a question is asked before. I made sure that they have the same data type and also checked my syntax, but I am still getting the error:

```
 ALTER TABLE meetings ADD FOREIGN KEY (ownerName) REFERENCES employees(name);
```

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
mysql> desc `meetings`;
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | room      | int(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | ownerName | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | ownerID   | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> desc `employees`;
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | name     | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | username | varchar(30)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | pswd     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: There's a good checklist for foreign keys in the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is not primary key in employees table so  .. try using `username`

```
ALTER TABLE meetings ADD FOREIGN KEY (ownerName) REFERENCES employees(username);
```

or as suggested  by DanielE or you can use the column `name` but need  an UNIQUE index for this column

Comment: Agreed but to complete your answer, you can add the foreign key on "name" if it's a PK or Unique in "employees" table.

Comment: @DanielE.   correct  ..  answer  updated . with your right suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Change the primary key of 'employees' from user name to name. Then you can use

```
ALTER TABLE meetings ADD FOREIGN KEY (ownerName) REFERENCES employees(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

What am I doing wrong? Error 1215 is probably the least of the problems here.

Some of the answers given for this question suggest making `username` the referenced column in `employees` rather than `name`, which is fine as far as it goes, but ignores some really fundamental issues in the schema and quite possibly wasn't the poster's intention for these columns. The rest of this answer is based on my own set of assumptions.

**meetings table**

Looking at the `meetings` table, I'm left wondering about the purpose of the `ownerID` column. Since the intention is to have `ownerName` as a foreign key to `employees`, what exactly is `ownerID`? The name suggests it also somehow references `employees`, but there is no `id` or `ownerID` in `employees`. Also, if any column starting owner... refers to an employee then why would you need both in the `meetings` table? One of them is surely redundant. Why is `ownerID` a VARCHAR(30)? ID columns tend to be INT. Of course, I may be reading to much into this and `ownerID` may have  some other purpose that has nothing to do with an employee, but if that's the case the name is likely going to cause confusion in the future.

The `meetings` table also has an INT surrogate key in `id`. There's another INT for `room`. Since `room` isn't a foreign key, it suggests that rooms are either consistently identified only by number (which would be strange in my experience) and that there is nothing more to a 'room' that's worth capturing (e.g. location, capacity, equipment etc.) to bother with modelling data about the room in a separate table (again unlikely). Alternatively, `room` might itself be a foreign key referencing an INT `id` column in an, as yet undefined, `rooms` table.

**employees table**

If we accept `ownerID` as a more appropriate foreign key to the employee that *owns* the meeting (it uses less memory to index than either `name` or `username`) then consistency would suggest another surrogate key `id` as the primary key in the `employees` table. It's not *necessary* to do this, `username` would be unique and is fine on it's own, but it's simpler and more efficient. The other suggestion made that `name` should be the PK in `employees` is wrong - it presupposes that names are always unique.

A single column to cover an employee name would also be unusual.

The point made about referencing a PK or a unique index is well made (even if it's not strictly necessary in Innodb), I'd just say that `ownerName` is the wrong foreign key and `username` and `name` are the wrong references because there is a better alternative.

And, finally, is a NULL password (`pswd`) a good idea?