# Mysql, how to show detailed error message

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I executed a SQL statement in MySQL workbench I got error message `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`. It only told me the result, but didn't tell me the reason. Is there any way to show more detailed error message?
[image]

Comment: I think it's about the way mysql is designed, this is what the best it can tell you about the error! Then you can come to SO and ask a proper question giving a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: MySQL isn't very good at telling the specific reason for a failed foreign key constraint, but I recommend you follow the checklist in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860