# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint laravel 5.6.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hello all i'm trying do migrate 
but i didn't work

this migration file

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chanels', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_chanel');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('id_owner')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_owner')->references('id_owner')->on('owners');
            $table->integer('id_responsable')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_responsable')->references('id_responsable')->on('responsables');
            $table->integer('id_teleport')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_teleport')->references('id_teleport')->on('teleports');
            $table->integer('id_provider')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_provider')->references('id_provider')->on('providers');
            $table->string('satelite');
            $table->string('frequency');
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id_user')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('chanels');
    }
```

but i get this issue [image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r06Uo.png)

thank you for your help

Comment: do you have owners table migrated??

Comment: What is the primary key of your owners called? I suppose `id`, so change `->references('id_owner')` to `->references('id')` also do this for all other keys

Comment: id_owner is the id name in owner table

Comment: In particular read the following answer in the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18180299/5389997

Comment: your reference name should be same as name of primary key of users table

Comment: the problem is all think are the same !