# mysql Error foreigh key relationship could not be added

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

[image][image: I'] I'm trying to make table relations in mysql. I'm using graphical interface. I have index on my columns. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Please provide snippets of the code SQL statement attempting to be executed. If there is no way for you to get that, then a more descriptive screenshot would be helpful. What I'm gathering from this is that you're attempting to add a row into a table that's utilizing a foreign key `id` from `quotes`, but there are no entries in `quotes` containing that `id`.

Comment: Please provide sql statement

Comment: I don't wirte sql statement. I'm using. I'm using graphical interface. I just add new picture.

Comment: Read this checklist of possible mistakes with foreign keys, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860