# Having issue defining a foreign key between two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

I'm not sure wher I am getting this issue, here are the two tables in question, any help would be much appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PHL_db`.`Session` (
  `year` INT NOT NULL,
  `season` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `division` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`year`, `season`, `division`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PHL_db`.`Team` (
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Free Agent',
  `Session_season` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Session_year` INT NOT NULL,
  `Session_division` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`, `Session_season`, `Session_year`, `Session_division`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Session_season` , `Session_year` , `Session_division`)
    REFERENCES `PHL_db`.`Session` ( `year`, `season` , `division`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: This error usually happens when a child table refers to records in a parent table which do not exist.  In your case, it might happen if `Team` refers to `Session` parent records which no longer exist.

Comment: Oh ok, I haven't had any inserts into the database yet so there are no records, would you know of a fix for this?

Comment: Fix the order in your `FOREIGN KEY` or `REFERENCES` clause so that session and year have the same position in both.

Comment: I was thinking that was an issue but wasn't 100%

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to make primary keys as foreign keys wherein primary keys cannot be used as foreign keys on the same table.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Session_season` , `Session_year` , `Session_division`)
REFERENCES `PHL_db`.`Session` ( `year`, `season` , `division`)
```

Should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Session_year`, `Session_season` , `Session_division`)
REFERENCES `PHL_db`.`Session` ( `year`, `season` , `division`)
```

The columns of the foreign key must match the columns of the referenced primary key. They must be the same:

- Number of columns
- Order of columns (this is the one you got wrong)
- Data types

You might also like to read this checklist on foreign key issues that I helped contribute to: [MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)

Comment: Interesting, so I changed them around to match but am still getting the error

Comment: You were right, I had to move those values around, thank you so much