# mySQL: Cannot add foreign key constraint when creation a table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to create this table

```
CREATE TABLE `t_plan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE `t_plan_x_currency` (
  `plan_id`             bigint(20)   NOT NULL ,
  `currency_symbol`     varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EUR',
  `price` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`plan_id`,`currency_symbol`),
  CONSTRAINT `t_plan_x_currency_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`plan_id`) REFERENCES `t_plan` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

but I got this error:

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: The datatype of both the columns must match for creating foreign key relationship.

Comment: You might like this checklist for foreign keys, which I contributed to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns involved in a foreign key relationship have to be of the same type. You have different types, `int(11)` for `t_plan.id` and `bigint(20)` for `t_plan_x_currency.plan_id`.

Make `t_plan.id` also a `bigint(20)`.

```
CREATE TABLE `t_plan` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `t_plan_x_currency` (
  `plan_id`             bigint(20)   NOT NULL ,
  `currency_symbol`     varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EUR',
  `price` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`plan_id`,`currency_symbol`),
  CONSTRAINT `t_plan_x_currency_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`plan_id`) REFERENCES `t_plan` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Or make `t_plan_x_currency.plan_id` an `int(11)`, what ever is more desirable for you.