# Can't set foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-workbench

I have a table called `citizens` with a primary key called `cpr`.

I have another table called `care`. In this table, I have also created a column with the name `cpr`. When I go into the `Foreign Keys` tab, I enter `fk_citizen_cpr` as the foreign key name, and reference the `citizens` table. Then I see checkboxes for the columns in the `citizens` table, but I can't check `cpr` or any of them for that matter.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I contributed to this checklist for what's required before you can create a foreign key, you might find it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Comment: @BillKarwin I went through the list, and it seems like everything is as it should be. The only difference between them as far as I can tell is that `cpr` in `citizens` is also a primary key, while in `care` it is not...

Comment: I tried deleting my tables and creating them again. Now it works for some reason...