# Error creating foreign key on numberofGPUs (check data types) - columns are exact same and I'm still getting this issue

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm setting up a database for an informatics class using PHPMyAdmin (no SQL or anything, just putting it straight into PHPMyAdmin), and currently I'm trying to set a foreign key in one of my tables to a primary key in another table. I keep getting this error: Error creating foreign key on numberofGPUs (check data types). I realized that one was a TINYINT and one was an INT, so I changed it so they're both INT's. I also noticed one was signed and the other wasn't, so I made them both unsigned. The foreign key constraint name is unique (I even changed it just in case it wasn't), and I'm honestly at a loss right now as to why it's doing this. I've even gone so far as to delete one of the tables (the one with the primary key) and completely remake it, just to have the same issue. Any help would be super helpful.

Below is the SQL code for creating the RUNNING_GPUS table, which has the primary key numberofGPUs:

```
CREATE TABLE `RUNNING_GPUS` (
`rigID` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `numberofGPUs` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `runningGPUs` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rigID`,`numberofGPUs`),
 KEY `rigID` (`rigID`),
 CONSTRAINT `rig-fk-for-running` FOREIGN KEY (`rigID`) REFERENCES `RIGS` (`rigID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Below is the SQL code for creating the RIGS table, which has the foreign key:

```
 CREATE TABLE `RIGS` (
 `rigID` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `rigName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `osVersion` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `numberofGPUs` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `rigLocation` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `lastPing` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
 `lastReboot` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
 `latestCrash` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
 `lostRevenuePerHour` decimal(5,4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `hardwareErrorType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hardwareErrorMean` decimal(7,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rigID`),
 CONSTRAINT `error-type-for-rigs` FOREIGN KEY (`hardwareErrorType`) REFERENCES `HARDWARE_ERRORS` (`hardwareErrorType`),
 CONSTRAINT `revenue-for-rigs` FOREIGN KEY (`lostRevenuePerHour`) REFERENCES `LOST_REVENUES` (`lostRevenuePerHour`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I'm also adding the foreign keys in through PHPMyAdmin, but when I tried to do the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE `RIGS`
ADD CONSTRAINT `test77`
FOREIGN KEY (`numberofGPUs`) REFERENCES `RUNNING_GPUS` (`numberofGPUs`);
```

it threw an error at me saying: #1005 - Can't create table `aetrigg_db`.`RIGS` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

ETA: I've been messing around with SQL Fiddle for a while now, and have all the tables in it. Everything works EXCEPT for this numberofGPUs. You can access the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec079e. I'm just adding the ALTER TABLE from above and adding it to the bottom, and it gets an error every time, saying that it can't add the foreign key. The RIGS table is the parent, and the RUNNING_GPUS is the child for the rigID column, but the RUNNING_GPUS is the parent and RIGS is the child for the numberofGPUs column. I tried to set it up by making the RIGS first, then the RUNNING_GPUS, and then altering the RIGS table, but that isn't working.

Comment: You would need to show the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables in order to get a proper answer.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and post the actual `CREATE` and/or `ALTER` statements.

Comment: You may like this checklist for foreign keys that I contributed to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Comment: You can see how to generate the statements here: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/tech-tips-tricks/how-to-generate-sql-create-table-script-using-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Are you creating this tables in this order? Also can you show the exact error message please?

Comment: it works perfectly fine if you execute it in the right order, see it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0cd30 (notice that I removed the FKs from rigs since it is not in your code)

Answer (score 1):

Swap the order in RUNNING_GPUS primary key

change
 PRIMARY KEY (`rigID`,`numberofGPUs`),
to
 PRIMARY KEY (`numberofGPUs`, `rigID`),

Foreign keys have to be a key themselves, of some sort, and apparently mysql doesn't consider secondary parts of a key to be of a key type.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/   Good reading material when you hit this issue.