# MySQL ERROR 1005 : Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Im a beginner in mysql, i don't understand my mistake 
its a problem with the foreign key of "membre" and "club".

```
CREATE TABLE club(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    INDEX club_nom_index (nom),
    adresse_id INT NOT NULL,
    nom_du_responsable VARCHAR(255) NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY club_adresse_id_fk (adresse_id) REFERENCES adresse(id)
);

CREATE TABLE membre(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    prénom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    adresse_id INT NOT NULL,
    club_id INT NOT NULL,
    rang_qualification INT NOT NULL,
    numéro_téléphone VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    courriel VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NULL,
    INDEX membre_courriel_index (courriel),
    nb_parties_gagnées INT NOT NULL,
    nb_parties_perdues INT NOT NULL,
    nb_parties_nulles INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY membre_adresse_id_fk (adresse_id) REFERENCES adresse(id),
    FOREIGN KEY membre_club_id_fk (club_id) REFERENCES club(id),
    FOREIGN KEY membre_rang_qualification_fk (rang_qualification) REFERENCES rang(qualification),

    INDEX nom_prénom_membre_index (nom, prénom),
    CONSTRAINT parties_gagnées_chk CHECK (nb_parties_gagnées >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT parties_perdues_chk CHECK (nb_parties_perdues >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT parties_nulles_chk CHECK(nb_parties_nulles >= 0)
);

CREATE TABLE tournoi(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    INDEX tournoi_nom_index (nom),
    club_id INT NOT NULL,
    date_début DATE NOT NULL,
    date_fin DATE NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY tournoi_club_id_fk (club_id) REFERENCES club(id),

    CONSTRAINT nom_date_unq UNIQUE (nom, date_début)
);

CREATE TABLE partie(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    membre1_id INT NOT NULL,
    membre2_id INT NOT NULL,
    résultat INT NULL,
    date_début DATE NULL,
    heure_début TIME NULL,
    id_tournoi INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY partie_membre1_id_fk (membre1_id) REFERENCES membre(id),
        FOREIGN KEY partie_membre2_id_fk (membre2_id) REFERENCES membre(id),
    FOREIGN KEY partie_tournoi_id_fk (id_tournoi) REFERENCES tournoi(id),

    INDEX membres_index(membre1_id, membre2_id),
    CONSTRAINT résultat_chk CHECK (résultat >= 0 AND résultat <= 2),
    CONSTRAINT membres_unq UNIQUE (membre1_id, membre2_id),
    CONSTRAINT date_heure_unq UNIQUE (date_début, heure_début)
);

CREATE TABLE adresse(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    adresse VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    rue VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ville VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    code_postal CHAR(6) NULL,
    INDEX adresse_code_index (code_postal),
    province_état CHAR(3) NULL,
    pays CHAR(2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT code_postal_chk CHECK (code_postal REGEXP '^[A-Z] 
        [[:digit:]][A-Z][[:digit:]][A-Z][[:digit:]]$')
);

CREATE TABLE rang(
    qualification INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NULL        
);
```

I was expecting the program to run but it keeps telling me that there is a problem with the foreign key in "membre" and "club".

Comment: You cannot reference a table that has not been created yet; move `adresse` and `rang` to the start of your script.

Comment: Could you…provide the actual errors that reference those foreign keys?

Comment: You have to Create the `adresse` table before you can create a foreign key to it in the `club` and `membre` table. Change the order you run the creates

Comment: So just move the `adresse` table to the top.

Comment: FYI, `CHECK` constraints are ignored prior to MySQL 8.0.

Comment: You might like this checklist for foreign keys that I contributed to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Answer (score 0):

You must change the order of the create statements.
First table `rang` and second table `adresse`, because the other tables have references to these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE rang(
    qualification INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NULL        
);

CREATE TABLE adresse(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    adresse VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    rue VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ville VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    code_postal CHAR(6) NULL,
    INDEX adresse_code_index (code_postal),
    province_état CHAR(3) NULL,
    pays CHAR(2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT code_postal_chk CHECK (code_postal REGEXP '^[A-Z] 
        [[:digit:]][A-Z][[:digit:]][A-Z][[:digit:]]$')
);

CREATE TABLE club(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    INDEX club_nom_index (nom),
    adresse_id INT NOT NULL,
    nom_du_responsable VARCHAR(255) NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY club_adresse_id_fk (adresse_id) REFERENCES adresse(id)
);

CREATE TABLE membre(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    prénom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    adresse_id INT NOT NULL,
    club_id INT NOT NULL,
    rang_qualification INT NOT NULL,
    numéro_téléphone VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    courriel VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NULL,
    INDEX membre_courriel_index (courriel),
    nb_parties_gagnées INT NOT NULL,
    nb_parties_perdues INT NOT NULL,
    nb_parties_nulles INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY membre_adresse_id_fk (adresse_id) REFERENCES adresse(id),
    FOREIGN KEY membre_club_id_fk (club_id) REFERENCES club(id),
    FOREIGN KEY membre_rang_qualification_fk (rang_qualification) REFERENCES rang(qualification),

    INDEX nom_prénom_membre_index (nom, prénom),
    CONSTRAINT parties_gagnées_chk CHECK (nb_parties_gagnées >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT parties_perdues_chk CHECK (nb_parties_perdues >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT parties_nulles_chk CHECK(nb_parties_nulles >= 0)
);

CREATE TABLE tournoi(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    INDEX tournoi_nom_index (nom),
    club_id INT NOT NULL,
    date_début DATE NOT NULL,
    date_fin DATE NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY tournoi_club_id_fk (club_id) REFERENCES club(id),

    CONSTRAINT nom_date_unq UNIQUE (nom, date_début)
);

CREATE TABLE partie(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    membre1_id INT NOT NULL,
    membre2_id INT NOT NULL,
    résultat INT NULL,
    date_début DATE NULL,
    heure_début TIME NULL,
    id_tournoi INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY partie_membre1_id_fk (membre1_id) REFERENCES membre(id),
        FOREIGN KEY partie_membre2_id_fk (membre2_id) REFERENCES membre(id),
    FOREIGN KEY partie_tournoi_id_fk (id_tournoi) REFERENCES tournoi(id),

    INDEX membres_index(membre1_id, membre2_id),
    CONSTRAINT résultat_chk CHECK (résultat >= 0 AND résultat <= 2),
    CONSTRAINT membres_unq UNIQUE (membre1_id, membre2_id),
    CONSTRAINT date_heure_unq UNIQUE (date_début, heure_début)
);
```