# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database for this project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ess/

I've created a database called `ess` via PHPmyadmin and when I run the SQL query to create the tables I get an error on the second table `areasuper`.

The error is: `` "#1005 - Can't create table `ess.areasuper` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")" ``

I don't really understand what I have been able to find online regarding this type of error so I'm hoping someone here can spell it out for me.
Also, I'm not sure how much info anyone will need to understand and replicate this so please let me know what to include if I have missed anything.
Thank you.

```sql
CREATE TABLE areas (
  area_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  area_name varchar(20) default NULL,
  area_desc varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  area_templ text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (area_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `areasuper`
--

CREATE TABLE areasuper (
  as_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  as_area_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  as_uid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (as_id),
  KEY as_area_id (as_area_id),
  KEY as_uid (as_uid),
  CONSTRAINT areasuper_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (as_area_id) REFERENCES areas (area_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT areasuper_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (as_uid) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `assignments`
--

CREATE TABLE assignments (
  assign_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  assign_uid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  assign_pid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  assign_eid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (assign_id),
  KEY assign_uid (assign_uid),
  KEY assign_pid (assign_pid),
  KEY assign_eid (assign_eid),
  CONSTRAINT assignments_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (assign_uid) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT assignments_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (assign_pid) REFERENCES positions (pos_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT assign_assign_eid_fk FOREIGN KEY (assign_eid) REFERENCES `events` (event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- 
-- Table structure for table `availabletimes`
--

CREATE TABLE availabletimes (
  avail_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  avail_uid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  avail_day char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  avail_start time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  avail_end time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (avail_id),
  KEY avail_uid (avail_uid),
  CONSTRAINT availabletimes_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (avail_uid) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `dayoff`
--

CREATE TABLE dayoff (
  day_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  day_uid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  day_start date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  day_end date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  day_desc varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (day_id),
  KEY day_uid (day_uid),
  CONSTRAINT dayoff_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (day_uid) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `events`
--

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  event_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  event_start time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  event_end time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  event_area_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  event_name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  event_comments text,
  event_date date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (event_id),
  KEY event_area_id (event_area_id),
  CONSTRAINT events_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (event_area_id) REFERENCES areas (area_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `positions`
--

CREATE TABLE positions (
  pos_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  pos_area_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  pos_name varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  pos_desc varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (pos_id),
  KEY pos_area_id (pos_area_id),
  CONSTRAINT positions_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pos_area_id) REFERENCES areas (area_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `supervisors`
--

CREATE TABLE supervisors (
  super_emp int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  super_super int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  KEY super_emp (super_emp),
  CONSTRAINT supervisors_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (super_emp) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `types`
--

CREATE TABLE `types` (
  type_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  type_name varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (type_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  user_name varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  user_pass varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
  user_first varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  user_last varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  user_email varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  user_phone1 bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  user_phone2 bigint(20) default NULL,
  user_type int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  user_pay_rate float(5,2) default '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (user_id),
  KEY user_type (user_type),
  CONSTRAINT users_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_type) REFERENCES `types` (type_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You might like to review https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860 which is a checklist of things you need for a foreign key to work. I contributed to that checklist.

Comment: A default value for a foreign key looks very suspicious. Do you really have `0` as ID in the referenced table?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.
I've edited the post to include the SQL for the first table that was created.

Comment: Can you share the DDL for your `users` table too please?

Comment: @Mureinik, I have added the full DDL I am trying to run. However it error's out at the  2nd table so none of the others have been created.

Comment: @TristenSweet `areasuper` has a key that references `users`. You need to create `users` before it.

Comment: @Mureinik, got it. Problem solved! Thanks everyone.