# MYSQL, errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, constraints, mysql-error-1064, alter-table, errno

I need help with this problem in MySQL. I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE syncproductscard(
  `idsyncproductscard` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idsyncproducts` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `carsa` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emsa` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filter` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsyncproductscard`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but alter table for add foreign key, does not work

```
ALTER TABLE syncproductscard 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_idsyncproducts` 
FOREIGN KEY (`idsyncproducts`)
REFERENCES syncproducts(`idsyncproducts`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

MySQL says:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `AAA`.`#sql-41d0_60` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")  0.016 sec

Comment: You should read this checklist for foreign keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Comment: Please read the section Foreign keys definitions are subject to the following conditions: of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html and if you think you have complied with these add the table definition for `idsyncproducts`

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the two tables and ensure they have the same properties.
`ENGINE = InnoDB`
`CHARSET = utf8`

You should be good to go.