# Cannot create table mysql(mariadb). Table is corrupted

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Some how, my database has gotten into a bad state. I previously had a table named live_stream. When I tried to drop a foreign key constraint, I got an error that mariadb could not rename `#sql-26_e7a` to `live_stream`. Now when I try to run the following statement, I get this error.

Can't create table `live_stream` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

`CREATE TABLE live_stream
(`id`bigint(20)        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);`

As you can see I don't have any foreign key constraints in the definition. If I try the exact same definition with a different table name, it works. If I try to drop the table, mariadb complains that live_stream doesn't exist. Its like the table or foreign key are stuck in a transaction or something like that.

I am using galara with maria db 10.3.

***UPDATE***

I believe the problem was introduced when a foreign key and unique index were given the same name. I recreated the scenario, and when I try to drop the index, mariadb prevents it.

*** UPDATE 2 ***
Here is the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
[image]

*** UPDATE3 ***

Here are the steps to reproduce.

create table tb1
(
    id bigint null,
    constraint tb1_pk
        primary key (id)
);

create table tb2
(
    id bigint null,
    tb1_id bigint null,
    constraint tb2_pk
        primary key (id),
    constraint tb2_tb1_id_fk
        foreign key (tb1_id) references tb1 (id)
);

ALTER TABLE `tb2` ADD CONSTRAINT `tb2_tb1_id_fk` UNIQUE (`tb1_id`, `tb1_id`);

drop index tb2_tb1_id_fk on tb2;

The problem is that the unique constraint has the same name as the foreign key and references the same column twice.

Comment: can you try CREATE OR REPLACE instead of just CREaTE

Comment: Could you give me an example? @Satya

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE live_stream (id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

Comment: @Satya same error :/

Comment: can you try this command on command prompt to see the error:  mysqlcheck -uroot -p <DATABASE> <TABLE>

Comment: Have you [tried to get more info about error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18180299/5444623)? ie `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

Comment: @PeterM, he is using GALERA

Comment: Isn't it using [InnoDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-is-mariadb-galera-cluster/) as a storage engine? or XtraDB, which is fork of InnoDB.

Comment: @PeterM I have updated the description wit the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

Comment: @Satya here is the output when I check the table with `CHECK TABLE live_stream`; Table 'live_stream' doesn't exist

Comment: Have you checked inside the 'MariaDB/data/dbname' folder if there's any file with `live_stream.*` name? Probably something like `live_stream.ibd` etc.?

Comment: @tcadidot0 No there isn't. But I did find these files. 
` -rw-rw---- 1 999 docker     45133 Oct 11 02:58 '#sql2-25-2.frm'
-rw-rw---- 1 999 docker     98304 Oct 11 02:58 '#sql2-25-2.ibd'`

Comment: What version?  I get `ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'tb1_id'` after the ALTER.