# Error when foreign referencing in mySQL (Error 3780)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am making two tables and I want the `personOne` column from table `b` to reference the `person` column on table `a`, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I have the below code as an example:

```
create table a(
person varchar(20),
cost varchar(10) not Null
)character set latin1
collate latin1_general_ci;


create table b(
personOne varchar(20),
personTwo varChar(2) not null,
key person_index (personOne),
CONSTRAINT C FOREIGN KEY (personOne) references a(person)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

It is telling me an error:

> Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'personOne' and referenced column 'person' in foreign key constraint 'C' are incompatible.

I tried to to set table a engine to InnoDB, but that didn't work. I researched the problem more but couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Your code works fine in all versions of MySQL (5.6, 5.7, 8.0) that I tried on dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57e5f8aed10c8575152dcf0ca868cb05

Answer (score 13):

The two columns must have the same collation. I'm guessing your table `b` is using the default collation for old versions of MySQL, which is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

You might like to review this checklist for foreign keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

I suggest the best choice is to declare both `a` and `b` tables with character set `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` if your version of MySQL is new enough to support it.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error code.
Although it may not help your situation, my problem was;

*The **ID** column in all my tables is set as `INT UNSIGNED` but I was using a **foreign key** of type `INT` signed.*

Comment: goddamnit this was it for me. I wouldn't have spotted that in a million year. Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here I had to first define a primary key in `a`:

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD PRIMARY KEY (person);
```

And pass the `COLLATE` value of `a`:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
...
)ENGINE=InnoDB 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
    COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```