# How to add primary and foreign key constraints correctly in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to alter tables to add the necessary primary and foreign keys, but I am really struggling to run the code without getting any errors.

The script I have written for adding PKs and FKs is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE PROJDEPT DROP CONSTRAINT PROJDEPT_pk;
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE DROP CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_pk DROP CONSTRAINT fk_EMPLOYEE;
ALTER TABLE PROJECT DROP CONSTRAINT PROJECT_pk DROP CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECT;
ALTER TABLE PROJECTTASK DROP CONSTRAINT PROJECTTASK_pk DROP CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK DROP CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK2;

ALTER TABLE PROJDEPT ADD CONSTRAINT PROJDEPT_pk PRIMARY KEY (Proj_Dept_ID);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_pk PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID);
ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD CONSTRAINT PROJECT_pk PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID);
ALTER TABLE PROJECTTASK ADD CONSTRAINT PROJECTTASK_pk PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID, Employee_ID);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_EMPLOYEE 
  FOREIGN KEY (Proj_Dept_ID)
  REFERENCES PROJDEPT(Proj_Dept_ID);

ALTER TABLE PROJECT
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECT 
  FOREIGN KEY (Proj_Dept_ID)
  REFERENCES PROJDEPT(Proj_Dept_ID);

ALTER TABLE PROJJECTTASK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK FOREIGN KEY (Project_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(Project_ID),
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK2 FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Employee_ID);
```

The ER Diagram I am trying to put into Oracle is down below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: **a)** You didn't post CREATE TABLE statements. Therefore, what are we supposed to do with bunch of ALTER TABLE ones? **b)** You mentioned "errors". Which "errors"? They aren't obvious at first glance. Because of a), they aren't obvious at second either. **Therefore**, I suggest you edit the question and provide quite a lot more details about what you did and which errors you got.

Comment: You tagged this question both [tag:mysql] and [tag:oracle]. You should be specific about which database you use, because it helps to get the attention of the experts who can give the best answer. I know Oracle Corp. owns the MySQL product, but in terms of tags here on Stack Overflow, the oracle tag refers to Oracle database, not MySQL.

Comment: You might like this checklist for common foreign key mistakes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860 That's about mysql, not oracle database, but the principles should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the constraints in the reverse order that you create them.

Also, you've misspelt `PROJECTTASK` as `PROJJECTTASK`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE PROJECTTASK DROP CONSTRAINT PROJECTTASK_pk
                        DROP CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK
                        DROP CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK2;

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE DROP CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_pk DROP CONSTRAINT fk_EMPLOYEE;
ALTER TABLE PROJECT DROP CONSTRAINT PROJECT_pk DROP CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECT;
ALTER TABLE PROJDEPT DROP CONSTRAINT PROJDEPT_pk;

ALTER TABLE PROJDEPT ADD CONSTRAINT PROJDEPT_pk PRIMARY KEY (Proj_Dept_ID);
ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD CONSTRAINT PROJECT_pk PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID);
ALTER TABLE PROJECT
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECT 
  FOREIGN KEY (Proj_Dept_ID)
  REFERENCES PROJDEPT(Proj_Dept_ID);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_pk PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_EMPLOYEE 
  FOREIGN KEY (Proj_Dept_ID)
  REFERENCES PROJDEPT(Proj_Dept_ID);

ALTER TABLE PROJECTTASK ADD CONSTRAINT PROJECTTASK_pk PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID, Employee_ID);

ALTER TABLE PROJECTTASK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK FOREIGN KEY (Project_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(Project_ID);

ALTER TABLE PROJECTTASK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PROJECTTASK2 FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Employee_ID);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0d76a0fdb896592319d3ae1f543b3d80)*