# Cannot create foreign key out of title columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I am trying to create a foreign key.

[image: Trying to Create Foreign Key]

The columns in both tables are VARCHAR(255) and neither is a PK, however I keep getting this error message:

[image: Foreing Key Error Message]

I can’t figure out how to make a fk out of the topics title and the posts’s topic_title.

Thank you in advance for your help, much needed.

Have a very nice day,
Ana

Comment: Please add the output from show create tables <tablename> for both tables as text to the question.

Comment: Also note that sequel pro hasn't seen updates in years and is not really compatible with modern mysql anymore.

Comment: You might like this checklist of foreign key errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have one to recommend for a mac osx?

Comment: Niiiice, thank you Bill Karwin

Answer (score 2):

Only define foreign keys to primary keys.  That is simply a best practice.

In order to add a foreign key in MySQL, though, you need to declare the column in the referred table as a primary key, as `unique`, or using an index.  I strongly discourage you from using just any key.  At the very least it should be `unique`.  But preferably a primary key.

Comment: "But preferably a primary key".
Could you give some reasons please ? (or links... ?)

Comment: _Only define foreign keys to primary keys_ Does that mean there should be only one foreign key in each table? Or does it mean that each foreign key should be a primary key in the referred table?

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much! I'll try that. Normally I wouldn't add a FK to a title, but I am using it on the client side in ReactJS as a key for a list, where my other foreign key wouldn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: @B001ᛦ . . . No.  That is referring to the *referenced* values.  And any table should be referenced using only one key (or set of keys).  Of course, the OP seems to. have a specific issue where referencing on a second, unique key might be appropriate.

Comment: @St3an . . . Just Google the question.  A primary key is *defined* as the column or columns that uniquely identify each row in a table.  A foreign key is intended to refer to a row in a table.  Voila.  The one is made for the other.  There are other reasons as well, but that should be sufficient to explain why primary keys -- which are explicitly defined to identify rows -- should be used for, well, identifying rows.