# Can not add foreign key constraint when creating new tables

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I'am creating a very new DB and i am getting this error when i try to add some foreign key to my tables
:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Here are my codes :

```
$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ft_img VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content text NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    role ENUM ('Author', 'Admin', 'Suscriber') NULL DEFAULT 'Suscriber',
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

//Create posts table
$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    user_id int NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    chapo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ft_img VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content text NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    published TINYINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USERS (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

//Create comments table
$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE comments (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    pseudo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content text NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    published TINYINT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");


// Create posts_comments table
$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE posts_comments (
    post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    comment_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, comment_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_post
        FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
        REFERENCES posts (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_comment
        FOREIGN KEY (comment_id)
        REFERENCES comments (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");
```

Error message : Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

I just can not figure out why i am getting this erro, if someone can help ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You have `posts` referencing `users` but there is no `users` table. You can't make a foreign key reference a table that hasn't been created yet. By analogy, you can't save a document file in a folder before you create that folder.

Comment: @BillKarwin hey sorry, i just forgot to copy it on my question, i actually do have this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
comment_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

These are `INT UNSIGNED`, but they are referencing primary keys that are `INT`.

The data types must be the same. Signed versus unsigned is enough to make them incompatible for purposes of foreign key references.

You might like this answer that I contributed to, which is a checklist of things that can go wrong with foreign keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860