# Create new column with foreign key into table error

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, incompatibletypeerror

I have a problem with creating a new `branch_id` column in the table `tn_whatsapp`.
Below are my SQL queries steps :

```html
1. ALTER TABLE tn_whatsapp ADD branch_id varchar(40) NOT NULL AFTER tenant_id;

2. ALTER TABLE `tn_whatsapp` CHANGE COLUMN `branch_id` `branch_id` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' AFTER `tenant_id`;

3. ALTER TABLE `tn_whatsapp` ADD CONSTRAINT `ibfk_branch_id` FOREIGN KEY (`branch_id`) REFERENCES `tn_branch` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Only in Step 3 query cannot add a foreign key and the error messages show -
`SQL Error (3780): Referencing column 'branch_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'ibfk_branch_id' are incompatible.`

This is my tn_whatapps table structure:

[image: img1]

This is my tn_branch table structure, id is branch_id in the tn_whatsapp table

[image: img9]

I want the expected result like the below picture:

[image: img2]

I am using HeidiSQL - version 12.0.0.6468

I have followed this StackOverflow answer [ERROR 3780: Referencing column and referenced column in foreign key constraint are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960902/error-3780-referencing-column-and-referenced-column-in-foreign-key-constraint-a) also cannot solve my problem.

May I know which parts I am getting wrong in step 3? Thanks.