# Why is there an error in my SQL foreign keys?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

```sql
CREATE TABLE BagelOrderLineItem (
  BagelOrderID INT NOT NULL,
  BagelID CHAR(2),
  BagelQuantity INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (BagelOrderID, BagelID),
  FOREIGN KEY (BagelOrderID) REFERENCES BagelOrder(BagelOrderID));
  
CREATE TABLE Bagel (
  BagelID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  BagelName VARCHAR(60),
  BagelDesc VARCHAR(30),
  BagelPrice DECIMAL(4,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (BagelID));
  
CREATE TABLE BagelOrder (
  BagelOrderID INT NOT NULL,
  CustID INT NOT NULL,
  OrderDate DATE,
  DeliveryFee DECIMAL(4,2),
  SpecNotes VARCHAR(60),
  PRIMARY KEY (BagelOrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES Customer(CustID));
  
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  CustID INT NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(30),
  LastName VARCHAR(60),
  Address1 VARCHAR(60),
  Address2 VARCHAR(60),
  City VARCHAR(30),
  State CHAR(2),
  Zip INT,
  MobilePhone VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (CustID));
```

I'm trying to connect the primary and foreign keys to each other, but I'm not sure what's wrong and SQL Fiddle just says "Cannot add foreign key constraint".

Comment: I recommend reading the checklist in the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the order in which you create the tables. You're referencing `BagelOrder` when you create `BagelOrderLineItem`, but at that point `BagelOrder` doesn't exist yet, so the reference fails. Try creating your Customer and Bagel first, then the BagelOrder and then BagelOrderLineItem.