# MYSQL Error 3780: Referencing column 'customer_id' and referenced column 'customer_id' are incompatible

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

I am using the book MYSQL Crash Course by Rick Silva to learn MYSQL. Using the book, I put in a code from Chapter 2 to learn about how foreign keys work and got an error message:

> Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'customer_id' and referenced column 'customer_id' in foreign key constraint 'complaint_ibfk_1' are incompatible.

The code I put in on MYSQL Workbench before I got the message was:

```sql
create table complaint
(
    complaint_id    int,
    customer_id     int,
    complaint       varchar(200),
    primary key (complaint_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references customer(customer_id)
);
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: You also need to provide the `create table` statement for the `customer` table.

Comment: If you're learning how foreign keys work in MySQL, you might like to refer to the checklist in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as the error states, the `customer_id` column in the `complaint` table and the referenced `customer_id` column in the `customer` table are incompatible - which probably means they have different data types.

For example:

```sql
create table customer (
  customer_id     varchar(20),
  primary key (customer_id)
);

create table complaint (
  complaint_id    int,
  customer_id     int,
  complaint       varchar(200),
  primary key (complaint_id),
  foreign key (customer_id) references customer(customer_id)
);
```

Gives the error:

> ```
> Referencing column 'customer_id' and referenced column 'customer_id' in foreign key constraint 'complaint_ibfk_1' are incompatible.
> ```

Because the referenced column is a `varchar(20)` data-type and the referencing column is an `int` data-type and is incompatible.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jB12fI1Z)