# Can someone check my code? It says the foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I tried running my code to make the table for my school end year project but it says that the foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed.Also it is in malay because that is the language my school uses.

```
create table `Kehadiran` (
   `IC_Guru` int(12) auto_increment,
   `Kod_Aktiviti` varchar(10),
   `IC_Murid` varchar(12),
   `Masa_hadir` varchar(20),
    
    primary key(`IC_Guru`)
    
    foreign key(`IC_Murid`)
    REFERENCES `kelas` (`IC_Murid`)
    on update cascade on delete CASCADE
)
```

Comment: @KenWhite `ON DELETE CASCADE` is very normal in foreign keys. I've never seen them in triggers.

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` command for `kelas`.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `primary key(`IC_Guru`)`. I think that must be a copying error, because you would get a syntax error rather than FK error.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts. This is a collection of good Q&A not a help desk. [tour]

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are missing one comma after the primary key definition. I don't know if this is in your original code, or just missing as you posted it here on Stack Overflow.

```
create table `Kehadiran` (
   `IC_Guru` int(12) auto_increment,
   `Kod_Aktiviti` varchar(10),
   `IC_Murid` varchar(12),
   `Masa_hadir` varchar(20),
    
    primary key(`IC_Guru`)
                          ^ missing comma here        
    foreign key(`IC_Murid`)
    REFERENCES `kelas` (`IC_Murid`)
    on update cascade on delete CASCADE
)
```

Besides that, you would get the error unless all of the following are true:

- You created table `kelas` before you try to reference it in a foreign key.
- The column `IC_Murid` in the `kelas` table is a primary key or unique key of that table.
- The column `IC_Murid` has the same data type (`varchar(12)`), character set, and collation as the column of `Kehadiran` that references it in the foreign key.

You may like to read this more complete checklist of foreign key requirements here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

I also wrote a chapter that explains possible foreign key errors in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).