cannot add a foreign key constraint to a new column
I wanted to ALTER an existing table and add a new column with a foreign key constraint .
I looked at Chat GPT and also some youtube videos which showed the same syntax so I used the following SQL:
ALTER TABLE comments ADD COLUMN Userid INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE comments ADD CONSTRAINT adding_fk FOREIGN KEY(Userid) REFERENCES Users(ID);

An error message is being shown when altering a table to add a column with foreign key:

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (facebook.#sql-2c80_8ad, CONSTRAINT adding_fk FOREIGN KEY
(Userid) REFERENCES users (ID)).

Why isn't it working?

You may like to review this checklist of foreign key problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860
