Getting error Can\'t create table clinic_app_auth.vitals errno: 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
I have made the below classes inheriting from BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Patients(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'patients'

    patient_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True)
    registration_date: Mapped[str] =  mapped_column(Date, nullable=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)

    user = relationship('Users', back_populates='patient')  # One-to-one relationship
    vitals = relationship('Vitals', back_populates='patient')


class Vitals(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'vitals'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True)
    weight_in_kg: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=True)
    height_in_cm: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=True)
    systolic_bp: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    diastolic_bp: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    pulse: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    temperature_in_celsius: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    oxygen_levels: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    measurement_dt: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, unique=True)
    notes: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(length=320), nullable=True)
    patient_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('patients.patient_id'), unique=True, nullable=False)

    patient = relationship('Patients', back_populates='vitals')

I have all the tables except I am not able to add vitals table.
show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_clinic_app_auth |
+---------------------------+
| patients                  |
| roles                     |
| user_profiles             |
| users                     |
+---------------------------+

What am I doing wrong here?

It looks like you reference a table users but you may not have created that table. Foreign keys cannot reference a table before it has been created.

@BillKarwin I have users  table already.

OK, I encourage you to review this checklist of potential foreign key problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Answering my question discovered by debugging,
I ran command SHOW CREATE TABLE patients;  and realized patinet_id is BigInteger when by default sqlalchemy orm was trying to create a foreign key column with integer.  So I set the column type to:
    patient_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('patients.patient_id'), unique=True, nullable=False)


which fixed the issue
