Encountering Error 1025 When Adding Foreign Key in Laravel Migration
am trying to add a foreign key to the mahasiswa table that references the prodi and jurusan tables in my Laravel project. Here is my migration code:
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('mahasiswa', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Adding columns if they don't exist
        if (!Schema::hasColumn('mahasiswa', 'prodi_id')) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('prodi_id')->nullable();
        }

        if (!Schema::hasColumn('mahasiswa', 'jurusan_id')) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('jurusan_id')->nullable();
        }

        // Adding foreign keys if columns exist
        $table->foreign('prodi_id')->references('id')->on('prodi')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->foreign('jurusan_id')->references('id')->on('jurusan')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('restrict');
    });
}


However, when running the migration, I get the following error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of '.\ta\#sql-2b2c_56b' to '.\ta\mahasiswa' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I have ensured that the prodi and jurusan tables exist and the id columns in both tables are primary keys. The data types for prodi_id and jurusan_id in the mahasiswa table are also the same as the data types for id in the prodi and jurusan tables.
Can anyone help me understand what's wrong and how to fix it? Thank you.
Adding Columns to the Table: I have tried adding the prodi_id and jurusan_id columns to the mahasiswa table if they did not already exist. This was an important step to ensure the table structure meets the requirements.

Adding Foreign Keys: I attempted to add foreign keys for prodi_id referencing the prodi table and jurusan_id referencing the jurusan table. This is crucial for maintaining data integrity between tables.
Checking Data Types: I ensured that the data types for prodi_id and jurusan_id in the mahasiswa table match the data types for id in the prodi and jurusan tables. This is a critical step to avoid errors when adding foreign keys.
Running the Migration: I tried running the migration to apply these changes to the database but encountered the error indicating an issue with the foreign key constraint.
Searching for Solutions: I have looked for information and tried to understand the cause of the error that appears, as well as seeking ways to fix it.
Can anyone help me understand what's wrong and how to resolve this issue? Thank you.


Ensure that the prodi and jurusan tables exist and have been migrated before running this migration.
Double-check that the id columns in prodi and jurusan tables are also unsignedBigInteger.
If you're still having issues, verify that all tables are using the InnoDB engine, which supports foreign keys in MySQL.

proodi and jurusan tble are exist and have been migrated also im verify that all tables are using innoDb engine

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860, it's a pretty comprehensive list of potential mistakes made when defining foreign keys in MySQL. You can use it as a checklist.

If you need further help, please post the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE as text for both the table you are modifying and the tables it references. Not the migration script, but the SQL DDL. We can only guess at the cause unless we see how the tables are actually defined, and migration scripts don't give enough information.

127.0.0.1/ta/jurusans/  http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/table/sql&db=ta&table=jurusans
Kueri SQL Anda berhasil dieksekusi.
SHOW CREATE TABLE prodi;
prodi CREATE TABLE prodi (
 id bigint(20) unsigned ...
this the prodi after i SHOW CREATE TABLE prodi @BillKarwin

How i tried before below the screenshot

If all else faols, try the 2nd most upvoted answer to the duplicate question - it shows you how to get more detailed info on the error from innodb regarding this error.
